# How can I implement OnPressed callback for Text widget, Flutter

Tags: text, widget, dart, flutter

I have a `Text widget` on pressing which another `Route` has to be shown. But I could not see any onPressed() method for the `Text widget`. Please Help.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Just wrap your title in a `GestureDetector` to handle clicks. Then call `Navigator`'s `pushNamed` to redirect to a new route.

```
new GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, "myRoute");
  },
  child: new Text("my Title"),
);
```

Comment: I got started with Flutter last week. It's literally the most amazing developer experience I've ever come accross. Wonderful.

Comment: Nice solution! Works really nice. But as a side comment, don't worry about `new` keyword, it is unnecessary in mostly (if not all) contexts in Flutter. Take a look to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50091389/473597 Thanks, Remi, for the solution.

Comment: @Ivanhercaz, take a look at the date of the answer :) in those times it was necessarily

Comment: Totally true, @neronovs! Thanks for pointing it!

Answer (score 44):

Use [InkWell](https://flutter.io/cookbook/gestures/ripples/)

this gives you nice ripple effect as well

```
 new InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, "YourRoute");
          },
          child: new Padding(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: new Text("Tap Here"),
          ),
        );
```

or

```
new FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, "YourRoute");
          },
          child: new Text("Tap Here"),
        )
```

Comment: FlatButton has been deprecated. Use TextButton instead.

Answer (score 22):

For **All the widget** of Flutter you can implement **onPressed**  using these widget

**1. InkWell() :** Using this widget you can add ripple effect on clicking

```
InkWell(
     onTap: () {
         Navigator.pushNamed(context, "write your route");
     },
     child: new Text("Click Here"),
 );
```

**2. GestureDetector() :** Using this widget you can implement, onTap, onDoubleTap, onLongPress and many more

```
GestureDetector(
     onTap: () {
         Navigator.pushNamed(context, "write your route");
     },
     onLongPress: (){
        // open dialog OR navigate OR do what you want
     }
     child: new Text("Save"),
 );
```

Comment: So you are combining both the answers and writing your own? I like that

Comment: No, I improve the above answers and write my own @iDecode

Comment: Point for explanations.

Answer (score 16):

You can use [TextButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton-class.html). Since it has a transparent background, it will look like a text widget.

```
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                //action
              },
              child: Text(
                'Title Text', //title
                textAlign: TextAlign.end, //aligment
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your text with `container` and then again wrap your text with widget `GestureDetector` and use `onTap()` in the following way

```dart
onTap: () {
  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: ((context) => *className()*)
  );
},
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to create clickable text.

> **InkWell**
> **GestureDetector**
> **TextButton**

---

```
Widget clickableText(Function() onShow) {
  return Column(
    children: [
      InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          onShow();
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Text one",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          onShow();
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Text one",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            onShow();
          },
          child: Text(
            "clickable text",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
          ))
    ],
  );
}
```