# Do you need to use the "new" keyword in Dart?

Tags: dart

In my Dart based application I just noticed that I can omit the `new` keyword and everything works perfectly fine.

Instead of `final widget = new Widget();` I can also use `final widget = Widget();`.

Does this have any effect in code?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

No, it does not. With [Dart 2 (click for the announcement with more information)](https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-80ba01f43b6#da82) the `new` and also `const` keywords were made **optional**.

This means that `new Widget()` does the exact same as `Widget()` on its own.

---

The `const` keyword can, however, change a value that would not be a `const` implicitly to a `const`.
So you will have to explicitly specify `const` when needed.

Comment: The Dart team had to retract a bit for now and there are some situations where `new` or `const` are still required (I don't remember examples or rules). They might make another attempt after Dart 2 to make it optional everywhere.

Comment: There are no places where `new` is required. If you omit `new` from a correct program, it will always keep working the same way. If you remove `const` from a working program, then in most cases where you would *have* to write `const` for the program to be valid, it will still be valid. Any time there is already a `const` surrounding the expression, you can omit the nested const.

Answer (score 25):

In Dart 2, if you invoke a constructor like a function, without a `new` or `const` in front, then it is equivalent to using `new`.
If you want a const invocation, then you should put `const` in front.

*Inside* a const expression, you don't need to write `const` again, and in some contexts that *require* const expressions (like switch case expressions and initializers of const variables), you don't even need the outer const.

So you don't ever need to write `new`.

<strike>Dart language team wants to allow expressions where you can insert either `new` or `const` and still have the invocation be correct (that is, a const constructor with constant arguments) to default to inserting `const` instead of `new`, hopefully in an early update to Dart 2.
For that reason, I recommend writing `new` it in front of `Object()`, or any other *const* constructor where you *need* the object to be a new instance. That's a very rare case, usually you don't care about the identity of your immutable object (which is why inserting `const` is considered a good idea).</strike> (That plan didn't pan out, so you can ignore this.)

Comment: The `new` and `const` keywords are different. They have a different effect in the memory usage in compilation and runtime.

Answer (score 6):

The `new` keyword was made optional in Dart 2. As of now, calling a class will always return a new instance of that class. As per my recommendation, you can use it (**NOT MANDATORY**) outside of a Layout definition, but omit in inside Layouts.

One more point which I would like to share with you guys is that if you use `new` or `const` keyword while declaring **widgets**, you are also able to see the **+ icon** which you can use to collapse and expand the widget body code. This is useful when you want to collapse/hide the rest widget code in **dart file** while working on another widget code in the same file.

Comment: Good catch on that collapse thing

Comment: The collapsing behavior would be IDE-specific.  You should explicitly state which one(s) it applies to.

Comment: Also, "calling a class" (by which I assume you mean "invoking a class's constructor") does not always return a new instance of the class.  If you invoke a *factory* constructor, you might get back an *existing* instance.  This is why `new` is discouraged: using it looks like it unconditionally creates a new instance when it might not.