# The new function in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm really new to programming with Dart and I'm currently following a Flutter tutorial to make a Unit Convert(Official  Google tutorial). I've been looking for some help lately and I saw that in every code in Dart for flutter it was written 'new' before some widgets. I was just wondering why because new never appears in the tutorial that I'm following.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do you need to use the "new" keyword in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091389/do-you-need-to-use-the-new-keyword-in-dart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New is no longer necessary in Dart 2.0.

It's superfluous - it will show up in old tutorials but you don't need to use it, and you should not.

Because Dart 2 is so new and so many tutorials available were written for Dart 1 it might be useful to read the changes between Dart 1 and 2:
https://www.dartlang.org/dart-2

Answer (score 0):

`new` became optional a few weeks ago.
`new` is used to call the constructors of a class to create a new object instance.

`const` is similar for const constructors but only optional in a const context.