# Flutter why need new when create widget?

Tags: flutter

```
Padding(
  child: Icon(Icons.search)
);

new Padding(
  child: new Icon(Icons.search)
);
```

The above two pieces of code achieve the same effect, when do us need to add "new"?

Comment: you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091389/do-you-need-to-use-the-new-keyword-in-dart

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [Dart 2.0](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200---2018-08-07) , `new` keyword is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter need 'new' keyword in the lower version when create a object.
In the newest version, 'new' keyword can be ignored