# Are nested Maps possible?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create Map object.

I'm new to dart and due to this, I'm trying it just like I would do it in JS, but this seems to be incorrect.

```
Map<String, Map> superMap = new Map();
superMap["subMap"] = new Map();
superMap["subMap"].addAll(StringStringMap1);
superMap["subMap"].addAll(StringStringMap2);
```

This results in:

```
Error: Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final', 'var' or a type name.
Try adding the name of the type of the variable or the keyword 'var'.
superMap["subMap"] = new Map();
^^^^^^^^
Error: Expected ';' after this.
superMap["subMap"] = new Map();
^^^^^^^^
Error: 'superMap' is already declared in this scope.
superMap["subMap"] = new Map();
^^^^^^^^
etc...
```

Comment: http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/01/maps-and-hashes-in-dart.html

Answer (score 2):

You syntax is non-idiomatic but correct.

The code you posted works (assuming that `StringStringMap1` and `StringStringMap2` are `Map` objects). I can successfully run the following code (as noted by [ישו אוהב אותך](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4758255), you need to wrap your code in a function, here `main` as the entry point):

```dart
main() {
  Map<String, Map> superMap = new Map();
  superMap["subMap"] = new Map();
  superMap["subMap"].addAll({1: 2});
  superMap["subMap"].addAll({2: 2});

  print(superMap);
}
```

I wanted to use this opportunity to share some idiomatic ways to write Dart code with you:

- You can omit `new` as it is not needed. [Learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50091389/6509751).
- Moreover, you can use `Map` literals to construct your maps. Your empty map assignment at the start would look like this:

```dart
Map<String, Map> superMap = {};
```

- Furthermore, you can use the `final` keyword for variables that are not reassigned later:

```dart
final superMap = <String, Map>{}; // The compiler can infer the type from the assigned value.
```

- With the `Map` literal, you can also move your other assignments for your `subMap` into the original assignment.
- Additionally, you can *spread* your other maps and thus move the `addAll` assignment to your original assignment as well.

The final result would look like the following. If that still does not work for you, I can come back to you:

```dart
main() {
  final stringStringMap1 = {'1': '2'}, stringStringMap2 = {'2': '2'};

  final superMap = <String, Map>{
    'subMap': {
      ...stringStringMap1,
      ...stringStringMap2,
    }
  };

  print(superMap);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your following code:

```
Map<String, Map> superMap = new Map();
superMap["subMap"] = new Map();
superMap["subMap"].addAll(StringStringMap1);
superMap["subMap"].addAll(StringStringMap2);
```

but it works when I change the `addAll` to this:

```
var maps = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"};
superMap["subMap"].addAll(maps);
superMap["subMap"].addAll(maps);
```

So, check if your `StringStringMap1` and `StringStringMap2` is correct.

But I suspect that **you haven't create the code inside a function**. So, try your code inside a `main`, something like this:

```
main() {

    Map<String, Map> superMap = new Map();
    superMap["subMap"] = new Map();
    superMap["subMap"].addAll(StringStringMap1);
    superMap["subMap"].addAll(StringStringMap2);

}
```

please be noted that in **Dart**, the entry point for the code is the `main()` function. You can't executed the line outside the function like in `Javascript`.