# Storing data in firestore for multiple layers

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I need to store data on multiple levels:
`Test 1 > q1, q2, q3... > question: hello, answer: opt 2, opt 1: a, opt 2: b, opt 3: c, opt 4: d`

So in actual terms I have multiples tests where in each test you have multiple questions and where each question has multiple options.

how can I add it to firestore and be able to load each test fast as at the moment it is delayed for long with the below code:

```
for (var i = 1; i < totalquestions + 1; i++) {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(user!.uid)
      .collection('Test $no')
      .doc(i.toString())
      .set(
        Map<String, dynamic>.from(
          Provider.of<Question>(context, listen: false)
              .question[i]!,
        ),
      );
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection('Test $no')
      .doc(i.toString())
      .update(
    {
      'yourAns':
          Provider.of<Question>(context, listen: false)
              .answers[i]!
              .values
              .first
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Nested fields in Firestore translate to nested `Map` objects in your Flutter code. Give it a try, and let us know if it doesn't work. ---- Consider whether the nested fields should be documents in a subcollection though. Pro's of that is that you can query them separately, load subsets of the data. The main cons of it is that you'll end up reading more documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki for everyone's visibility.

As mentioned by Frank, nested fields in Firestore translate to nested `Map` objects in Flutter. A thing to consider is whether the nested field should be `documents` in a `subcollection`. It will enable you to query them separately and load subsets of data, but you'll end up reading more documents. Here's a comprehensive [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478074/are-nested-maps-possible) on nested Maps in flutter.