# What does 'new' mean in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a difference between the following two statements in Dart?

```dart
new Container()
// vs
Container()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference. The `new` keyword was mandatory at some point, but was made optional with Dart version 2.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50091390/6509751) for more information. You can also mark your question as a duplicate above using the comment I posted.