# Is there any case in dart where using 'new' keyword is necessity?

Tags: flutter, dart, new-operator

I have recently jumped to dart after learning core java. Using the similar concept of java, I have tried creating an object of the class 'Product' using the `new` keyword to which dart warned "Unnecessary new keyword".

```
void main() {
 Product oil = new Product('sunflower', 2, 300);
 final noodles = Product('waiwai', 20, 20); //name, qty, price
}
```

So, my question is what advantageous is it for us to omit `new` in dart and if there are still any situations where using `new` keyword is absolutely necessary since it is not completely omitted?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091389/do-you-need-to-use-the-new-keyword-in-dart this is answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do you need to use the "new" keyword in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091389/do-you-need-to-use-the-new-keyword-in-dart)

Comment: @Bhavin To some extent, yes but what I also want to know is if omitting the `new` works just as fine, why is it not completely removed? 
Also, I could see a comment saying "The Dart team had to retract a bit for now and there are some situations where new or const are still required (I don't remember examples or rules)." So, I am hoping to learn with example too.

Comment: It wasn't removed because that would break existing Dart code. `new` is never required. (`const` is a different story.)

Comment: There is a feature as of dart 2.15 (https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-15-7e7a598e508a) called constructor tear-offs, which allows you to refer to the default constructor of your class with `Product.new`. This is essentially a method named `new` rather than the `new` keyword, but in any case a constructor tear-off is the only place you should use `new`.

Answer (score 2):

The advantageous of omitting `new` is one doesn't need to write redundant letters and can safe the time. The Dart compiler can differentiate the object creating from another.

But there is one place in Dart where you still need `new` - tear-offs constructor. For example:

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  boxPutter(Box.new); // new style with tear-offs constructor
  boxPutter((something) => Box(something)); // old style
}

class Box {
  Box(this.staff);
  final int staff;

  @override
  String toString() => 'Box($staff)';
}

void boxPutter(Box Function(int something) constructor) {
  final staffGenerator = 10;
  print(constructor(staffGenerator));
}
```